# Yet another 'module is not defined' in Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm pretty new to angularjs, and I'm trying to test an app using Jasmine and Karma. The tests work fine if I just use the basic framework that Jasmine provides (with SpecRunner.html), but when I try to use Karma I keep getting the same 'module is not defined' message.

My file dependencies in karma.conf.js are as follows:

```
files: [
  '../../js/angular.min.js',
  '../../js/angular-sanitize.min.js',
  'lib/angular-mocks.js',
  '../../js/app.js',
  'lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js',
  'lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine-html.js',
  'lib/jasmine-2.4.1/boot.js',
  'lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js',
  'spec/spec.js'
]
```

So far this looks exactly like all the previous karma undefined module questions I've seen on SO, except I'm quite sure that angular-mocks.js is included, file locations are correct, and I'm not using any other framework that might be overriding karma.conf.js. I apologize for asking the same question again, but am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: Whats the exact error message that you are getting?

Comment: @Jon 'ReferenceError: module is not defined', which traced down into angular-mocks.js and jasmine. I would post a fuller trace, but I don't seem to be able to reproduce the error after following Nocomm's solution...

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues with Karma in the past.  It is picky about the order that you put the dependencies into.  For instance, if you are using JQuery and Angular, then Karma will want JQuery before Angular.  I see that you placed Angular before all of its submodules, which is great.

I would place the dependencies in this order:

```
files: [
  'lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js',
  '../../js/angular.min.js',
  '../../js/angular-sanitize.min.js',
  'lib/angular-mocks.js',
  'lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js',
  'lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine-html.js',
  'lib/jasmine-2.4.1/boot.js',
  '../../js/app.js',
  'spec/spec.js'
]
```

I've also had problems using minified and unminified versions of Angular modules in the same application.  For instance, if you want to use minified versions of Angular, then make sure all of its submodules are minified too.  I would say the same for any JavaScript dependency.  Keep it consistent.

Comment: And problems like this are why it's worth considering using RequireJS, even if only for your tests.  The Karma module has to load all of these script files, and in the order of required dependencies.  Once you hit a situation where two different modules use conflicting dependencies (which is fine for the overall app), you'll see the need for RequireJS.

Comment: That's a good point.  It's hard to keep up with all of the JS tools and frameworks.  There are just so many of them that I haven't had time to look into learning about/using RequireJS.

Comment: I thought I was being clever earlier when I realized that using wildcards in the config file was causing some of my js to be loaded in the wrong order, but I never thought that jquery was part of it! Well, I both changed my dependency order and pointed to an unmin'd version of angular.js, which seems to have solved the module issue. But for some reason even after reverting those changes I can't reproduce the error. I'm getting an “TypeError: Cannot read property '$injector' of null” message, but I suppose that's something else I'll have to figure out. Thanks for the help!